# Error when using TtsState in flutter_tts package in flutter: Error: Type 'js.JsObject' not found

Tags: javascript, flutter

I am using [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) and the TtsState enum to check the state of Tts. E.g:

```
  TtsState ttsState = TtsState.stopped;
```

However, when I use this, I need to import import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts_web.dart';

And then when I run the project I get this error:

Error: Type 'js.JsObject' not found.

[image]

I have made a custom enum as workaround in the meantime, but interested to know how to actually fix this error which appears related to JavaScript compatability?

I have updated flutter, reinstalled flutter_tts, run flutter clean etc but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Presumably, you are not developing for the web? The main question is why you want to use that enum when it isn't used in flutter_tts (not web). Are you just using it rather than defining your own state enum?

Comment: Good point. I've defined my own enum, but might want to make the app available for web later so was wondering what was causing this error. But at anyrate, it's working fine now with a custom enum.